# Access denied to mysql using root

Tags: mysql, root, access-denied

I have created another user, and I have provided all rights to that new user using **Phpmyadmin**, then i revoked rights from **root** user, while i was creating user, i gave it password, as well as i pushed the **"Generate password"** button, i have both the passwords, now the newly created user does not work, and the root does not have the rights to either access the table or show the users.
i just want those tables and databases. Its in xamp in my local computer.

Any helps :)

Comment: try the query - **FLUSH PRIVILEGES** . this reread the tables into the memory

Comment: This has at least given me the rights to see those databases through the command line, but through phpmyadmin and mysql workbench, i still do not see the other tables. is there a way i can make root to be the super privileged user. even when i am doing:
SELECT User from mysql.user;
it denies access to this user on the user table.

Comment: The FLUSH PRIVILEGES has only worked once, now I do not have access to the databases again :(